# Show data from structure in UITableView

Tags: swift, tableview, structure

I think I'm missing something when it comes to tableviews in Swift 4 or maybe I'm just not passing my data like I should.. 
I read a json that I'm supposed to save in the structure "Workspace" and then I use this same structure to show data in my tableview

I have this class:

```
public class User {

    var Wor = [Workspace]()
    var WorData = Workspace()

}
```

And this structure: 
The getuserWorkspace function is supposed to updates the structure values.

```
struct Workspace: Decodable {
    var guid: String
    var name: String

private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
    case guid = "guid"
    case name = "name"
}

init(){
    self.guid = "guid"
    self.name = "name"
}

mutating func getUserWorkspace(base: String, completed: @escaping () -> ()){
    let url = URL(string: "SOME URL")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.addValue("Basic \(base)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request){ (data, response, error) in
        if error == nil {
            do {
                let rep = try JSONDecoder().decode([Workspace].self, from: data!)
                print(rep) 
                //it prints exactly what I receive so I guess I'm saving it well? 
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completed()
                }
            }catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

And I have this in my view controller:

```
   var co = User()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    co.getBase()
    co.WorData.getUserWorkspace(base: co.Base) {
        print("success")
        self.listView.reloadData()
        self.updateVertically()
    }
    print("guid " + co.WorData.guid)
    print("name " + co.WorData.name)
    print("work ", co.WorData)
    print("wor ", co.Wor)
    listView.delegate = self
    listView.dataSource = self
}
```

In the tableview rows I'm returning `co.Wor.count`

And in the cell row `co.Wor[indexPath.row].name`

But everything is blank
And the prints give me this :

```
guid guid
name name
work  Workspace(guid: "guid", name: "name")
wor  []
[Proj.Workspace(guid: "8a81b08e45467656fr467f51119047027", name: "test ok")]
(this print is inside the function in the structure)
success
```

I'm really confused on how to solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- It's preferred to set dataSource and delegate top of `viewDidLoad`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
   listView.delegate = self
  listView.dataSource = self
}
```

2- Assign the data after you get it

```
mutating func getUserWorkspace(base: String, completion: @escaping (_ arr:[Workspace]?) -> void ){
  let rep = try JSONDecoder().decode([Workspace].self, from: data!)
  completion(rep)
}
```

//

```
  co.WorData.getUserWorkspace(base: co.Base) { (arr) in 
    print("success")
    self.co.Wor = arr
    self.listView.reloadData()
    self.updateVertically()
}
```

Comment: I just changed the delegate & datasource!

But I'm not sure on how to assign the data
These two lines are inside a function in the structure in which I didn't call the User class so I can't write self.co.wor = rep, the workspace has no member called "co" ...